# Can controller in MVC have async calls to database?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm adding a business data layer to my project and currently I'm connecting it to an MVC application. I am going to have controllers which answer to views and controllers which will be for WebApi so that I can make async AngularJS calls.

Do I need to implement both async and sync calls to my data or can I use the async functions for the classic MVC controller? (I'm not sure how the communication between view and controller is implemented so I'm afraid if I might cause some issues since by default it's making sync calls to database)

Comment: You can simply wrap the synchronous code in `Task.Run()`, unless you prefer to use, say, Entity Framework's built-in async logic.

Comment: So the only issue can be of slight performance if is don't use EF builtin async?

Comment: Making use of the Task Parallel Library (TPL, the underlying implementation of `Task`, `Task<T>`, etc.) adds some overhead (all those state machines to track completion). The benefit it not making the individual call faster, but allowing the worker thread to do something else. Without TPL each blocking call will hold up one thread, with that thread can service another request while the resource (database, …) hasn't returned its data. So rather than 1000 concurrent requests requiring 1000 threads, you use far fewer thus reducing overall machine load.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> or can I use the async functions for the classic MVC controller?

You certainly can. At least in the more recent versions of MVC (I cannot recall when support was added).

You don't need to do anything special, just mark your actions `async` and return `Task<ActionResult>`.

You can freely mix blocking and asynchronous methods within the action.

Eg.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Details(id) {

  var res = await db.Entities.FindAsync(id);
  if (res == null) {
    return HttpNotFound();
  }

  return View(res);
}
```

Comment: Yeah but im not connecting from my controller directly to my db but to my business data layer so it will look differently. I suppose you answer my question only I `await` for a different function

Comment: @DominikDitoIvosevic Yes, you'll need your business layer to expose its functionality via waitable functions (whether using C#5's `async` or TPL directly.